# Extract the address from a "mov rcx, qword ptr [0xAddress]" x86 instruction with C++

Tags: c++, pointers, assembly, x86-64, machine-code

I haven't found a solution to my problem. What I am wondering about is how  I can do this in C++.

I have a address that points to the location `mov rcx, qword ptr [0xAddress]`.
Then I need to find a way to get the [0xAddress] pointer from that memory location with only C++, without using inline asm.

```
//I want something like this, but I don't get it working.
DWORD64 PatchAddress = FindAddressLocation(); //This finds the mov rcx, qword ptr [0xAddress]. location.
uint64_t rcx = *(volatile uint64_t*)PatchAddress;//This is supposed to give me the [0xAddress] address
*(BYTE*)(rcx) = 0;//Then write 0 to the pointer 0xAddress
```

Comment: It returns a other address than the one inside the [] :/

Comment: Offsets are 32 bit even in 64 bit code. You need to use `uint32_t`.

Comment: If `PatchAddress` points to the instruction, the `mov rcx,` part appears first and `[memory_address]` comes one or two bytes later (check the x86 instruction format for details).

Comment: @BoPersson how can i do that in c++?

Comment: @gofmode - If `PatchAddress` is a specific address in memory, consider what `PatchAddress + 1` might be.

Comment: @Bo, 3 or 4 bytes later, FYI. See my answer. And thanks for putting me on the right track--I didn't understand what he was trying to do until I saw your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual encoding of `mov rcx, [a]` is rip-relative:

```
48 8b 0d DD CC BB AA
```

The signed offset, AABBCCDD, is relative to the next instruction. If this is the encoding being used, your C++ code should be:

```
DWORD64 PatchAddress = FindAddressLocation();
uint64_t addr = PatchAddress + 7 + *(int32_t *)(PatchAddress + 3);
*(BYTE*)addr = 0;
```

The other encoding, which is not RIP-relative, uses the SIB byte:

```
48 8b 0c 25 DD CC BB AA
```

In this case, the address is a 32-bit signed address. The C++ code would be:

```
DWORD64 PatchAddress = FindAddressLocation();
uint64_t addr = *(int32_t *)(PatchAddress + 4);
*(BYTE*)addr = 0;
```

Comment: Then again `FindAddressLocation` is a misleading name if it returns the beginning of the instruction rather than the address part. OP should have been more specific.

Comment: @Jester, Yeah, I was pretty confused by his description at first. But I think this is what he wants.